# Primefaces inline editing of datatable not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, editing, inline-editing

I am trying to provide a possibility to inline-edit a row of a datatable with primefaces, but it doesn't seem to work properly. I can visually edit the values but when I click the save-icon, it doesn't update the changed values...

Here is the code:

Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="ticketTypePrices" var="priceCategoryTicketType" 
    value="#{EventInstanceController.priceCategoryTicketTypes}"
    editable="true">
            
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{EventInstanceController.onEditPrices}" />  
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{EventInstanceController.onCancelPrices}" update="@this" />
    
<p:column headerText="Preiskategorie">
    <h:outputText value="#{priceCategoryTicketType.priceCategory.name}" />
</p:column>
                
    <c:forEach  items="#{EventInstanceController.ticketTypes}" var="item">
        <p:column headerText="#{item.name}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{priceCategoryTicketType.ticketTypes[item]}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText converter="bigDecimalConverter" value="#{priceCategoryTicketType.ticketTypes[item]}" style="width:50%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
    </c:forEach>
                
    <p:column style="width:3%">
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

EventInstanceController.onEditPrices

```
public void onEditPrices(RowEditEvent event) {
        PriceCategoryTicketType pctt = (PriceCategoryTicketType)event.getObject();
        
        System.out.println(pctt.getPriceCategory().getName());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < priceCategoryTicketTypes.size(); i++) {
            PriceCategoryTicketType pctickettype = priceCategoryTicketTypes.get(i);
            if(pctt.getPriceCategory().equals(pctickettype.getPriceCategory())) {
                for(Map.Entry<TicketType, BigDecimal> entry :  pctt.getTicketTypes().entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("TicketType: " + entry.getKey().getName());
                    System.out.println("Price: " + entry.getValue());
                }
                priceCategoryTicketTypes.set(i, pctt);
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks like this:
[image: Overview of the datatable]

As you can see, the default values of each cell is 0.
If I change the values (like on the picture) to f.e. 30 25 20 and hit the save-row-icon, the values will change back to 0 0 0.

The System.out.println in the onEditPrices results to following:

```
INFO: TicketType: Standard
INFO: Price: 0
INFO: TicketType: AHV
INFO: Price: 0
INFO: TicketType: Student
INFO: Price: 0
```

Am I missing something? :(

Info: I'm using primefaces version 4.0 (snapshot) but also tried and failed with stable version 3.5

Thanks in advance,
Xera

Comment: I had a similar problem. It was because of value in the datatable. The list must not be changed during process. Please post the bean class.

Comment: what is 'c:forEach' doing inside datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Review your entity, maybe some validations are not considering or validations in the database, I solve problems putting nullable=true in entity's columns and admitting null values in some fields of the corresponding table.
If your data conflicts some restrictions doesn't work.